# How to set an output parameter that is the combination of two fields, e.g., fullname=firstname+lastname?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that would return the full name of a customer based on their ID as the sole input parameter. The full name would be the first name + the last name contained in the table. I'm pretty sure there's something (a lot) wrong with my code, though... Can you help me spot the problem, please? Thanks!

```
alter procedure udemy
@businessID int,
@firstname varchar(max) output,
@lastname varchar(max) output,
@fullname varchar(max) output
as
begin
select firstname,lastname
from person.Person
where @businessID=BusinessEntityID and
@firstname=FirstName and
@lastname=LastName
set @fullname=@firstname+@lastname
end
```

Comment: _columns_, not fields...

Comment: What's the problem with the given code? What does happen when you call it? Is there any error message given?

Comment: Aside: Typically the first and last names are separated, e.g. `FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName` or `FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName`. Note that if either the first or last name is NULL then the result will be NULL. Using `FullName = ConcatWS( ' ', FirstName, LastName )` will return a string regardless of NULLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a stored procedure that would return the full name of a customer based on their ID

Simply assign it to the variable

```
alter procedure udemy
@businessID int,
@fullname varchar(max) output
as
begin
  select @fullname=firstname + lastname -- Retuen Full Name
  from person.Person
  where @businessID=BusinessEntityID --Based on ID
end
```

Then call your `SP` as

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(MAX); --Declare the OUTPUT parameter

EXEC dbo.udemy 1, @FullName OUTPUT; --Pass an ID and the OUT parameter

SELECT @FullName; --See the results
```

So, there is no need to the other two parameters, unless you want to return the `FirstName` and the `LastName` too.

Also, why you use them in the `WHERE` clause since you have the `ID`? in the same time you specify `OUTPUT` for both.

---

If you don't want to use the `OUTPUT` parameter then

```
alter procedure udemy
@businessID int
as
begin
  select firstname + lastname -- Retuen Full Name
  from person.Person
  where @businessID=BusinessEntityID --Based on ID
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sami. Your code does not return any results when I execute the procedure, it just says commands executed successfully.

Comment: @Jurij That mean you pass an ID which doesn't exists in your table

Comment: it happens with existing IDs as well

Comment: @Jurij See the updates. It seems like you don't know how to execute an `SP`

Comment: sami I do know how to execute a stored procedure. you just don't always need a select statement when you execute it, i.e., I was just executing it this way: declare (atsign)fullname varchar(max)
exec udemy 1, @fullname output

Comment: actually, could you explain why I need the select statement in the execution if I already have it in the sp? Thank you sami

Comment: @Jurij For the first one, yes you need to select the value in the _@FullName_ paramter, cause the SP is just set the value in it, for second one, the sp will directly return the result for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the assignment you need in the `select`:

```
alter procedure udemy (
    @businessID int,
    @firstname varchar(max) output,
    @lastname varchar(max) output,
    @fullname varchar(max) output
) as
begin
    select @firstname = firstname,
           @lastname = lastname,
           @fullname = @firstname+@lastname
    from person.Person p
    where BusinessEntityID = @businessID;
end;
```

Comment: thank you gordon. I tried executing the procedure after altering it as above but it just prints commands executed successfully, there's no result set

Comment: @Jurij . . . Of course there is not result set.  You are setting values in output parameters, not returning a result set.

Comment: but the sp contains a select statement so I don't understand why nothing is showing up? Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Jurij . . . `SELECT` statements either return a result set or set scalar variables (or insert the result set into a table if you have an `INTO` clause).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query and you need to write output parameter in select as shown below.

```
Create Table Person (BusinessEntityID int, firstname varchar(10), lastname varchar(10))
insert into Person Values (1, 'Suraj', 'Kumar'),(2, 'Deepak', 'Kumar')
go
Create procedure udemy
@businessID int,
@fullname varchar(max) output
as
begin
  select @fullname=firstname + lastname
  from Person
  where BusinessEntityID = @businessID
end
go
DECLARE @get VARCHAR(20);
EXEC udemy 1,@get output

SELECT @get
```

The output is as `SurajKumar`
You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/LELW66837)

Comment: thank you, it sure works but I will ask you the same question I asked some users above--why do I need to SELECT when I execute the procedure if the procedure contains a SELECT statement already? I really want to grasp this concept. thanks

Comment: I think this is for distinguish between normal parameters and output parameters and just a way or you can say as syntax defined by Microsoft.

Comment: You can up vote the answer if it is right as it motivate me and also it helps other user to find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CONCAT why go through all complications.

```
CONCAT(First_Name, '*space*', Midle_Name,'space', Last_Name) AS Full_Name
```

This is your query corrected

```
alter procedure udemy
@businessID int,
@firstname varchar(max) output,
@lastname varchar(max) output,
@fullname varchar(max) output
as
begin
select CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS Fll_Name --Here you go
from person.Person
where @businessID=BusinessEntityID and
@firstname=FirstName and
@lastname=LastName
set @fullname=@firstname+@lastname
end
```